# Keyboard shortcut to comment lines in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

In **[Sublime Text 2](https://www.sublimetext.com/2)**, how do I enclose a selection in a **comment**?
Is there a keyboard shortcut for this action?

Comment: Don't forget to use the `<kbd>` tag in your answers, guys. It adds the proper emphasis to the keyboard shortcuts you're sharing. See my answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19389142/901641 - hit `edit` on my answer to see exactly how I used the tag.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

By default on Linux/Windows for an English keyboard the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to toggle a block comment, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to toggle a line comment.

If you go into `Preferences->Key Bindings - Default`, you can find all the shortcuts, below are the lines for commenting.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
```

Comment: The default doesn't work for me on Windows. I'm using a laptop, that might be why, i dunno. This worked though, thanks.

Comment: As Vadim notes, on Mac the commands are `cmd+option+/` and `cmd+/`, respectively.

Comment: So what about super, instead of command? I see the Linux syntax in my default key bindings, and I've successfully used it in my user key bindings.

Comment: If you're a mac user with spanish keyboard you would use this in your user custom key bindings:
[
 { "keys": ["alt+minus"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
 { "keys": ["alt+shift+minus"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]

Comment: So what is "Ctrl+Shift+/" supposed to mean? Don't i need "Shift+7" already to achieve "/"? How would "Ctrl+Shift+/" and "Ctrl+/" be any different from each other then? It's things like that, why shortcuts often don't work.
For me, on a Windows 7 machine, answers suggesting "Ctrl+7" are correct.

Comment: @noshky - yes, my answer seems to be only valid for people using GB or US keyboards, I've updated it to be explicit about that. (The forward slash key "/" is it's own key on a GB/US keyboard)

Comment: @AndrewBarrett That command doesn't seem to work for Cypher (CQL), but it has always worked for my other files. How can I change my settings such that Cypher knows to comment out lines as well with the same command?

Answer (score 89):

In the "Preferences->Key Bindings - User"

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
   { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

Just paste it, these are will work great !

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10 with an Spanish (Latin American) keyboard layout

Answer (score 20):

I'd like to add, that on my mac by default block comment toggle shortcut is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 14):

For German keyboards use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> to toggle a block comment and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> to toggle a line comment.

The shortcut in `Preferences->Key Bindings - Default` is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, but to actually use the functions, press the keys stated above.

Comment: Don't suppose you could advise me on how to assign to the hash key? I'm trying to make a shortcut for the 'reindent' command but it's having none of it.
Trying: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+#"], "command": "reindent" }`
Is there an issue using the **#** character in JSON?

Comment: @GrahamR.Armstrong As the shortcut in that file is assigned to `Ctrl+/` and one needs to press `ctrl + #` to use the function, I would suggest you try to use `/` to assign that key. I don't know what that JSON parser does with the # character.

Answer (score 10):

In a Brazilian Portuguese ABNT2 keyboard I have a similar issue to the one reported by JoshDM. In the file sublime-keymap I have:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
```

But I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. On my keyboard, <kbd>;</kbd> is on the left of <kbd>/</kbd>.

It seems like a bug.

Comment: Same thing here, no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 9):

you need to replace "/" with "7", it works on non english keyboard layout.

Answer (score 8):

This did the trick for me coming from Brackets and being used to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on the numpad.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

In my keyboard (Swedish) it´s the key to the right of "ä": "*".

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

In keyboard (Spanish), SO: Win7.

Go into Preferences->Key Bindings - Default, 
replace`..."ctrl+/"]...` by `"ctrl+7"...`

And don't use the numpad, it doesn't work. 
Just use the numbers above the letters

Comment: Works great for non EN keyboards

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac with a US keyboard, you want <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: Works not only for Python, but for C and Ruby too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like some kind of keyboard mapping bug. I'm Portuguese, so I'm using a PT/PT keyboard. Sublime Text 3 apparently is handling <kbd>/</kbd> as <kbd>~</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Max OS: If you want to toggle comment multiple individual lines versus block comment an entire selection, you can do multi line edit, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> **and** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>....

```
[

{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+d"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

First Open The Sublime Text 2.

And top menu bar on select the `Preferences`.

And than select the `Key Bindings -User`.

And than put this code,

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },

    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

I use **Ctrl**+**Shift**+**C**, You also different short cut key use.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop with spanish keyboard, the problem seems to be the "/" on the key binding, I changed it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and now it works.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
```