# Keys mapped to different keys

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In my default key bindings I have `ctrl+/` for comment by default. But it only works if I press `ctrl+;` in my keyboard. Whats wrong?

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676623/determine-if-a-key-sequence-has-already-been-assigned-in-sublime-text/16676749#16676749).  It may help.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt. It shown exactly what I said and just that.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that sublimetext is assuming a wrong keyboard layout?

Edit: It seems to be a keyboard conflict in some keyboard layouts.
Check some of the answers from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11598840/125801). Some of the workarounds may apply.

Comment: AFAK only this key. How to fix it?

Comment: its a bug. There is no fix.